# Error in deploying EAR on WAS8: javax.servlet.UnavailableException: SRVE0201E: Servlet org.test.TestSoapBindingImpl]: not a servlet class

Tags: java, linux, jax-ws, websphere-8

I have developed a sample webservice project on JAXWS web service and trying to deploy the ear on remote machine which has linux OS and IBM webspehre 8, I am getting error as below:The same application when deployed on windows machine works and same application which is deployed on local machine with linux os also works.

I have tried restarting the server on remote machine but its not working.How to resolve this issue.

```
 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp commonInitializationFinally SRVE0266E: Error occured while initializing servlets: {0}

                                 javax.servlet.UnavailableException: SRVE0201E: Servlet [org.test.TestSoapBindingImpl]: not a servlet class

        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper$1.run(ServletWrapper.java:1495)
```